# UICollection View to display data from parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I've been trying to get a standard `UIcollectionView` to display information pulled from Parse and it is not working at all. All I need is a simple way to implement a Collection view to show the name of the item with an image to display the item. The number of items in each section is equal to the PF query. count that was performed. But I need to figure out how to display the items and how to create a working collection view.

Comment: You need to show some effort in how you tried to solve this problem (post some code of what you've tried). As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: @rdelmar - +1.
OP -[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) is the how to go about the Collection View. Regarding the PF query, a sample of the response that you are getting from Parse will be required to figure out what you are trying to use as your data source to your collection view. If it is plain JSON then it should be straightforward using either RestKit or AFNetworking.

Comment: @rdelmar  I Figured out how to receive data From Parse.com, but thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) for UICollectionView.

It has nothing to do with the Parse or PFQuery at the moment.